# How to disable/enable all children on LinearLayout in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

Is there way by programming that all the children of a certain layout?

For example i have this layout with two children:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <SeekBar android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></SeekBar>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/textView2" android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

and i want to do something like:

```
LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
myLayout.setEnabled(false);
```

In order to disable the two textviews.

Any idea how?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

A LinearLayout extends ViewGroup, so you can use the getChildCount() and getChildAt(index) methods to iterate through your LinearLayout children and do whatever you want with them.  I'm not sure what you mean by enable/disable, but if you're just trying to hide them, you can do setVisibility(View.GONE);

So, it would look something like this:

```
LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
for ( int i = 0; i < myLayout.getChildCount();  i++ ){
    View view = myLayout.getChildAt(i);
    view.setVisibility(View.GONE); // Or whatever you want to do with the view.
}
```

Comment: Without using setVisibility(View.GONE) ,it is possible to disable/enable all children on LinearLayout in Android

Comment: How do I do it for nested Layout @SBerg413

Answer (score 15):

You can also disable/enable  without using setVisibility()

Add a View.OnClickListener to your CheckBox then pass the View you want to be disabled into the following function...

```
private void enableDisableView(View view, boolean enabled) {
    view.setEnabled(enabled);

    if ( view instanceof ViewGroup ) {
        ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup)view;

        for ( int idx = 0 ; idx < group.getChildCount() ; idx++ ) {
            enableDisableView(group.getChildAt(idx), enabled);
        }
    }
}
```

with the following reference [Is there a way to disable all the items in a specific layout programmaticaly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818013/is-there-a-way-to-disable-all-the-items-in-a-specific-layout-programmaticaly/5257691#5257691)

Comment: Blatant copy from http://stackoverflow.com/a/5257691/953010, you could at least have given credit.

Answer (score 7):

Why not just doing the setVisibility(View.GONE) on the layout itself, rather than iterating through the children?

Comment: You might have a custom view containing some other customs views. You might want to hide the random views hanging on your custom view but not the views in the custom view itself. It's pretty common on libraries for example. If you hide the custom view you are hiding everything, not just the childs added by the users of your library.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe is late, but you can just add `android:duplicateParentState="true"` in the child of the `LinearLayout`

Something like this:

```
 <LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/container"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="vertical">

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textA"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:duplicateParentState="true"
         android:text="First Text"/>

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textB"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:duplicateParentState="true"
         android:text="Second Text"/>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add another transparent layout that will match_parent of the original view and change it visibility to visible when you want to disable all the children and to enable children then just change visibility to gone

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: you can check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10480560/how-to-disable-any-event-on-a-view-in-android