# StateListDrawable doesn't work in a custom view

Tags: android, view, background, custom-controls, statelistdrawable

I'm facing with big problem with StateListDrawable on a custom view.
I've a custom view that inherits directly from LinearLayout, and in its XML layout, the background is a simple state list drawable that sets the view's background enabled or disabled in order of its current state. What i don't understand is why if i call

```
this.SetEnabled(false);
```

in my custom view, background does not change.

Maybe my question is not very clear, so i've done a simple example.
You can download it [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/60231308/StateListDrawableSample.rar).
Look at the "ViewCustom.java" file and find FIXME tag.

Hope someone can help me.

P.S.
The same state list drawable associated to a Button works, but on my custom view don't.

ViewCustom.java

```
public class ViewCustom extends LinearLayout {

public ViewCustom(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    //Inflate layout
    final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_custom, this);


    /**FIXME: Try to set "enabled" to false in order to get the
     * "panel_disabled" background, but it doesn't work. 
     */
    this.setEnabled(false);
}
```

}

View.custom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="@drawable/sld_panel"
   android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```

sld_panel.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/panel_disabled" android:state_enabled="false"/>
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/panel_enabled" android:state_enabled="true"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: Please include the code to the example in your question.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto - I've attached code as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, you can't disable just a Linear Layout. What you would need to do is disable everything in it. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7687934/544198) answers that, but it boils down to one of two things.

1. You can make the layout disappear, by `setVisibility(View.GONE)`.
2. You can iterate through each item in the View, by something like this:

   ```
   for ( int i = 0; i < myLayout.getCount();  i++ ){
       View view = getChildAt(i);
       view.setEnabled(false); // Or whatever you want to do with the view.
   }
   ```

Comment: yeah, it was so simple! i tried to cycle over the LinearLayout's child collection and disable all items in it. It works pretty good...thanks!