# How to disable all nested children of linear layout in android?

Tags: java, android

In android if I have a linear layout object, and it has a bunch of stuff inside it like textviews, more linear layouts which contain more linear layouts. How can you just disable (`.setEnabled(false);`) everything in that given linear layout?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by disabling? do you want to delete them?

Comment: I want to use the setEnabled and set it to false. Which makes the control unusable and grayed out.

Comment: You can create a `newLinearLayout`, store `youcurrentLinearLayout` in it, then delete `youcurrentLinearLayout` childs with the code below.

Comment: Updated check my answer

Answer (score 1):

Something like that:

```
for(int i = 0; i < ((LinearLayout) YourLinearLayout).getChildCount(); i++){
  ((View)((LinearLayout) YourLinearLayout).getChildAt(i)).setEnabled(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

[How to disable/enable all children on LinearLayout in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7687784/how-to-disable-enable-all-children-on-linearlayout-in-android)

Comment: But this removes the view from the screen, I want to use `.setEnabled(false)` method, so it makes it unusable and grayed out.